# Windows 7 Explorer keyboard shortcut: set focus to files/folders/content area?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, gui

### Is there a Windows 7 Explorer keyboard shortcut to set focus to files/folders/content area (depicted below)?

This has bothered me for so long...
I want to set my explorer window's focus to the files pane (shown below). What's the most efficient way to do that with a keyboard?

[image]

Here's what I've been doing:
- Tab / Shift+Tab to move focus through interactive window elements until it looks like a selection rectangle appears over one of the files in my window.
- Alt+V, Alt+D to change appearance setting of a folder contents' icons. Doesn't always work, depending on what's selected at the time.

Comment: The Easiest way is to open an explorer window and press `SPACE` bar on keyboard. Works fine on Windows7. So `Win+E` --> `SPACE`

Comment: Now tell me how you really feel...

Comment: +1 for the artwork :))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to move the keyboard focus to the file pane. In this example, I use the hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>**+**<kbd>Space</kbd>:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; Windows Explorer
    #Space::
        ControlFocus, DirectUIHWND3, A
        SendInput, {Space}
        return
#IfWinActive
```

---

**See Also:**

- [AutoHotkey: **Hotkeys**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Perfect. Now I am wondering why I was tolerating tabs all these days. I should have googled earlier

Comment: In Windows10, **Win + Space** is now used for switching input languages.

Answer (score 32):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, that should do it.

For the record the terminology you are referring to is called ["Property Tab Navigation"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) ...

> Properties control

```
CTRL+TAB/CTRL+SHIFT+TAB: Move through the property tabs
```

Comment: wow. this worked. never would have thought. but the (usless) *search webpages* box kills it.

Comment: Does not work in Windows 10.

Comment: @RashaMatt ~ This is for Windows 7 ... long before Windows 10 mate.

Comment: @RashaMatt ~ I can confirm this does work in Windows 10.

Comment:  amazing, didn't know that and I'm using Windows for ~30 years.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Works in Windows 7, 8.1, 10

Comment: The question was asking for a Windows 7 solution, does this also work for Windows 7?

Comment: Yes it also works in Windows 7.

Comment: `CTRL` + `E` navigates to the search input  not the content pane.

Comment: And `esc` navigates from the search input back to the content pane. It works, if you takes the time to actually read and understand all six words in the post.

Comment: Does not work for me. Although works if instead of `Esc` you use `SPACE`

Comment: For me in Win10 , if focused on **Column/DisplayStyle/Sidepanel**, then `Ctrl+Tab` works; but for **Back/Fwd/History/Up/Path/Search** I have to `Ctrl+Tab (twice)` (strangely, press2 doesn't have to directly follow press1 , e.g. `Ctrl+Tab, LArrow, Tab, Ctrl+Tab`).

Answer (score 7):

I came here because I'm looking for a solution too.

The fastest way I found to do that was to go back and forth: use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Almost always works.

Comment: That's nice trick. Never thought about it

Comment: Alt-UP navigates upward in the file hierarchy, which is not what the poster asked for.

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions I use: -

The first is from this [Microsoft support thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-explorer-left-or-right-hand-pane-menu/65e5f3d2-8898-4bfb-9680-dd6c07257644) where they recommend a [third party app](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/) which focuses on the window under the mouse if you use the scroll wheel - which is rather handy now considering the segmented approach to Explorer.

And the other, keyboard only, is the `Alt+D` hotkey to focus the address bar, then press `Shift+Tab` twice to bring the focus to the file list (the first `Shift+Tab` focuses on the sorting headings).  A third `Shift+Tab` sends focus to the folder pane.

Comment: A proposed edit to this answer was made, using `Ctrl+Tab` instead of `Shift+Tab`.  I just tested it and `Ctrl+Tab` is more reliable, so use that - failing that then try `Shift+Tab`.

Answer (score 2):

A compromise...
Hide the menu along the top of the Explorer window. Go to:
**Tools -> "Folder Options..." -> "View" tab -> Deselect "Always show menus"**

Now focus can be moved from the left and right panes (shown below) using **Tab** & **Shift+Tab**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have just opened the Explorer window you can press <kbd>Space</kbd> (thanks to a @mnmnc's comment).

Otherwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> seems to always work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to iglvzx for the AutoHotkey solution. Unfortunately, it didn't always work for me, because sometimes the focus would be on the first column header in detail view. Pressing the space there causes the contents to be resorted. To fix that problem, I wound up changing the code to use a mouse click instead. Here is the new code:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ; Windows Explorer

   #Space::

  ; Get coordinates of content control within explorer window
  ControlGetPos, x, y, w, h, DirectUIHWND3, ahk_class CabinetWClass

  ; Offset to get past column headers in Details View
  x += 100
  y += 30

  ; Send a mouse click to change focus to content window
  SendInput, {Click %x%, %y%}

  return

#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice. Just as fast as any keyboard shortcut and you don't have to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

Type: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> if the navigation pane is present.

Type: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> otherwise.